# Show a new line in a Text component in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I want to display some text using the Text composable in Jetpack Compose and the text contains a new line character '**\n**'. Something like below:

`Text("This is the first line\nThis is the second line")`

But the '**\n**' ends up just being text.

How can I get the Text component to display the new line on a separate line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `Text("This is the first line\r\nThis is the second line")`. This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

I just tried and i can see new line on preview and real device. Not sure if its about compose version or just bug. [image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

\n should work, at least on the platforms I tested.

You said "something like" -- if you are actually passing a string literal then \n will be replaced with a newline at compile time.  But if you are loading the string from a file, etc, its possible that the \n was not replaced.  Try:

```
val s = origString.replace("\\n","\n")
Text(s)
```

This will force the replacement of \n at runtime.